# Java Unchecked Overriding Return Type

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, abstract-class, return-type

I have a project that has the following components:

```
public abstract class BaseThing {
    public abstract <T extends BaseThing> ThingDoer<T, String> getThingDoer();
}

public class SomeThing extends BaseThing {
    public ThingDoer<SomeThing, String> getThingDoer() {
        return Things.getSomeThingDoer();
    }
}

public class SomeOtherThing extends BaseThing {
    public ThingDoer<SomeOtherThing, String> getThingDoer() {
        return Things.getSomeOtherThingDoer();
    }
}

public class Things {
    public ThingDoer<SomeThing, String> getSomeThingDoer {
        return getThingDoer(SomeThing.class);
    }

    public ThingDoer<SomeOtherThing, String> getSomeOtherThingDoer {
        return getThingDoer(SomeOtherThing.class);
    }

    private <D extends ThingDoer<T, String> D getThingDoer(Class<T> clazz) {
        //get ThingDoer
    }
}

public class ThingDoer<T, V> {
    public void do(T thing) {
        //do thing
    }
}

public class DoThing {
    private BaseThing thing;

    public void doIt() {
        thing.getThingDoer().do(thing);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compiler warning in `SomeThing.getThingDoer()` that says:

> Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion.
>
> Found `ThingDoer<SomeThing, String>`, required `ThingDoer<T, String>`

Everthing compiles fine, and while I didn't get a chance to test out `DoThing.doIt()` yet, I have no reason to believe that it won't work.

My question is, can this break and is there a better way to do this? I could make `DoThing` a base class, and have subclasses for both `SomeThing` and `SomeOtherThing` but that doesn't seem very elegant.

**EDIT:** I would like to avoid making `BaseThing` generic.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let's look first at your `BaseThing` class that you don't want to make generic:

```
public abstract class BaseThing {
    public abstract <T extends BaseThing> ThingDoer<T, String> getThingDoer();
}
```

This is *not* a generic class, but it contains a *generic method*.  Frequently, generic methods like this are designed so that the type `<T>` is bound by the compiler based on some argument to the method.  For example: `public <T> Class<T> classOf(T object)`.  But in your case, your method takes no arguments.  That is also somewhat common, in cases where the implementation of the method returns something "universally" generic (my term) like this method from the `Collections` utility class: `public <T> List<T> emptyList()`.  This method takes no arguments, but the type `<T>` will be *inferred* from the calling context; it works *only* because the implementation of `emptyList()` returns an object that is type-safe in all cases.  Due to *type erasure*, the method doesn't ever actually know the type of `T` when it's called.

Now, back to your classes.  When you create these subclasses of `BaseThing`:

```
public class SomeThing extends BaseThing {
    public ThingDoer<SomeThing, String> getThingDoer() {
        return Things.getSomeThingDoer();
    }
}

public class SomeOtherThing extends BaseThing {
    public ThingDoer<SomeOtherThing, String> getThingDoer() {
        return Things.getSomeOtherThingDoer();
    }
}
```

Here, you want to override the `abstract` method from the base class.  Overriding the return type is allowed in Java *as long as the return type is still valid in the context of the original method*.  For instance you can override a method that returns `Number` with a specific implementation that always returns `Integer` for that method, because `Integer` *is a* `Number`.

With generics, however, a `List<Integer>` **is not** a `List<Number>`.  So while your abstract method is defined to return `ThingDoer<T, String>` (for some `T extends BaseThing`), your overloads that return `ThingDoer<SomeThing, String>` and `ThingDoer<SomeOtherThing, String>` are not generally compatible with some unknown `T` even though `SomeThing` and `SomeOtherThing` both extend from `BaseThing`.

The caller (from the abstract API) expects some unknown, unenforceable `T` that cannot be guaranteed to be satisfied by either of your concrete implementations.  In fact, your concrete overloads are no longer generic (they return specific, statically-bound type parameters) and that conflicts with the definition in the abstract class.

**EDIT**:
The "correct" way (no warnings) to define the abstract method should be something like:

```
public abstract ThingDoer<? extends BaseThing, String> getThingDoer();
```

This makes it clear to the caller that it's getting a `ThingDoer` with its first type parameter bound to *something* that extends `BaseThing` (so it can use it as if it were a `BaseThing`) but the caller **will not** know the specific implementation when accessed by the abstract API.

**EDIT #2** - Findings from our discussion in chat...

The OP's original example usage is:

```
BaseThing thing = /* ... */;
thing.getThingDoer().do(thing);
```

Notice how the same `thing` reference is passed back into a method in the object returned from that same thing's `getThingDoer()` method.  The object returned by `getThingDoer()` needs to be tightly bound to the concrete implementation type of `thing` (according to the OP).  To me, this smells like broken encapsulation.

Instead, I suggest exposing the logical operation as a part of the `BaseThing` API and encapsulating the delegation to the `ThingDoer` as an internal implementation detail.  The resulting API would look something like:

```
thing.doTheThing();
```

And implemented somewhat like:

```
public class SomeThing extends BaseThing {
    @Override public void doTheThing() {
        Things.getSomeThingDoer().do(this);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherThing extends BaseThing {
    @Override public void doTheThing() {
        Things.getSomeOtherThingDoer().do(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand exactly what's going on. It is working however, so I guess my question is can this break somehow, and is there a more "correct" way of doing it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I tried that and got errors with `thing.getThingDoer().do(thing);` saying `capture <? extends BaseThing> in ThingDoer cannot be applied to BaseThing`

Comment: That could very well be, depending on your usage.  I compiled my example your way (got an unchecked warning) and with my edit (no warning) but didn't try to *use* it because I'm not sure what your ultimate use case is for this.  From the look of it, perhaps the Visitor pattern would be of more use rather than Generics.  Generics is useful to restrict which types of objects you accept, but a Visitor is for taking advantage of polymorphism to adapt to different implementations (assuming the set of implementations is fixed).

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw my use case (it is at the bottom of the code block in the question). Given that it works (albeit with a warning), would you say that it's worth investing time into getting a warning free implementation?

Comment: Well, your `ThingDoer` is parameterized specifically to a particular `<T, V>` but without also making `BaseThing` generic such that they use the exact same `T` (which you said you didn't want to do) you're going to be stuck because an unbound `T` in `BaseThing` cannot be guaranteed to match a specific (but independent, and therefore potentially different) `T` in the returned `ThingDoer`.  Even if it works in your one circumstance, the unchecked warning means that I **could** write something that would break type-safety at runtime.  Whether *you'll* ever write one of those cases, I cannot say.

Comment: Yes, but in this situation the unbound `T` has to extend `BaseThing`. It is implicit in the actual implementation of my code that a subclass of `BaseThing` will have a corresponding `ThingDoer`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52646/discussion-between-william-price-and-eliezer)