# Why this covariant return type declaration doesn't produce an unckecked warning?

Tags: java, jls, covariant-return-types

Why doesn't the following code produce a compile-time unchecked warning:

```
class Parent {
    public List method(){
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public List<String> method() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

while the following actually does:

```
class Parent {
    public List<String> method(){
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public List method() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm actually looking for a reference for this behaviour in the JLS.

Comment: Look for [Java Unchecked Overriding Return Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645753/java-unchecked-overriding-return-type).

Comment: @DimaSan it doesn't actually explain why my first example doesn't produce a compilation warning while the later does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `List` is not a subtype of `List<String>` but (as you know) `List<String>` *is* a subtype of `List`.

Examples given in the JLS:

```
class C implements Cloneable { 
    C copy() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (C)clone();
    } 
}
class D extends C implements Cloneable { 
    D copy() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (D)clone();
    } 
}
```

This represents your first example where the return type in the child is a subtype of the parent. Likewise, in your example, `List<String>` is a subtype of `List`.

> [4.10.2. Subtyping among Class and Interface Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2)
>
> Given a generic type declaration `C<F1,...,Fn>` *(n > 0)*, the direct supertypes of the generic
>   type `C<F1,...,Fn>` are all of the following:
>
> - The direct superclass of `C<F1,...,Fn>`.
> - The direct superinterfaces of `C<F1,...,Fn>`.
> - The type `Object`, if `C<F1,...,Fn>` is a generic interface type with no    direct superinterfaces.
> - **The raw type `C`.** *(boldness mine)*

While:

```
class StringSorter {
    // turns a collection of strings into a sorted list
    List<String> toList(Collection<String> c) {...}
}
class Overrider extends StringSorter {
    List toList(Collection c) {...}
}
```

is an example of your second snippet.

> An unchecked warning would be given when compiling `Overrider` against
>   the <strike>new</strike> definition of `StringSorter` because the return type of
>   `Overrider.toList` is `List`, which is not a subtype of the return type of
>   the overridden method, `List<String>`. *(striking mine)*

[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) examples [8.4.8.3-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e13595) & [8.4.8.3-2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#d5e13600) and specifically:

> [8.4.8.3. Requirements in Overriding and Hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3)
>
> If a method declaration *d1* with return type *R1* overrides or hides the
>   declaration of another method *d2* with return type *R2*, then *d1* must be
>   return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for *d2*, or a compile-time error
>   occurs.
>
> This rule allows for covariant return types - refining the return type
>   of a method when overriding it.
>
> If *R1* is not a subtype of *R2*, a compile-time unchecked warning occurs
>   unless suppressed by the `SuppressWarnings` annotation (§9.6.4.5).

Comment: Is `List<String>` a subtype of the raw `List`?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel, "A raw type is the name of a generic class or interface without any type arguments." So, a `List<String>` is a list with its type parameter defined.

Comment: From the JLS, `If R1 is not a **subtype** of R2, a compile-time unchecked warning occurs unless suppressed by the SuppressWarnings annotation (§9.6.4.5).` and your statement, `This represents your first example where the return type in the child is a subtype of the parent.`, that would explain why the warning isn't issued in my first example, but I can't find it clearly in the JLS where it says that `List<String>` is actually a **subtype** of `List`, please clarify.

Comment: "Raw" types should be used for legacy code; they give up type checking. So, you can add anything you want into it and it does not care if you give it `String`s or `Integer`s (together); it's all `Object`s to it.  So, I don't see the reason for an unchecked warning in that case. Whether or not the JLS explicitly says `List<String>` is a subtype of the raw type `List` will take me a moment to run down. I will be offline for a few hours.@JaimeHablutzel

Comment: Found it, from JLS8 §4.10.2: `Given a generic type declaration C<F1,...,Fn> (n > 0), the direct supertypes of the
generic type C<F1,...,Fn> are all of the following: ... - The raw type C.`.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel, nice find!. I added the necessary parts from your finding to the answer to make it complete. I see now that I put too much emphasis on the second part when the first was really what you were asking about; apologies.